# python append syntax error with a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, append, syntax-error

My goal is to make a list called residuals that returns a list that has the absolute value of each element minus the average, I'm also returning data at the end because that is the list I am using. I got this far but am getting a syntax error with `residuals.append(new_number)`.

```
data = [92.5, 87.7, 74.8, 93., 91.7, 90.0, 90.3, 92.5, 100.0, 
  100.0, 35.7, 37.4, 21.0]

def residuals(number):
    residuals = []
    for element in number:
        new_number = abs(element - float(avg(number))
        residuals.append(new_number)
        print residuals
residuals(data)
```

Comment: You forgot a `)` on the preceding line: `abs(element - float(avg(number))`, so the `abs(...` call is still incomplete.

Comment: You should also avoid reusing the identifier `residuals`.  Good rule is to have every name refer to no more than one thing.

Answer (score 5):

I want to share a technique for figuring out when you've made this particular typo, which I believe I learned from Clark Weissman's [*Lisp 1.5 Primer*](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/book/Weismann_LISP1.5_Primer_1967.pdf) (PDF).  You read through the expression with the wrong number of parentheses, character by character, counting.  Every time you come to a `(` you count up one, and every time you come to a `)` you count down one.  When you get to the end, your count should be zero.

```
    new_number = abs(element - float(avg(number))
                    1               2   3      21
```

Here, the count at the end is greater than zero, so we know there is a missing close paren.  If it were less than zero, we would know we had left out an open paren.  Note that it does *not* tell you *where* to add the parens.  In a construction like

```
 x = foo(a, bar(b, baz(c, d), e)
        1      2      3    2   1
```

the missing close paren might belong after `b`, `c`, `d`, or `e`, and we have to know something about the functions being called to tell which.

Comment: I do not think that the downvote is valid, as this gives a basic hint on how to find these kind of typos in the future

Comment: I just read first two lines of this, and instantly knew my mistake.